# Eliminating array rows based on a property of consecutive pairs of elements

Tags: arrays, numpy

We are given an array sample `a`, shown below, and a constant `c`.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 3, 1, 11, 9, 14],
              [2, 12, 1, 10, 7, 6],
              [6, 7, 2, 14, 2, 15],
              [14, 8, 1, 3, -7, 2],
              [0, -3, 0, 3, -3, 0],
              [2, 2, 3, 3, 12, 13],
              [3, 14, 4, 12, 1, 4],
              [0, 13, 13, 4, 0, 3]])
c = 2
```

It is convenient, in this problem, to think of each array row as being composed of three pairs, so the 1st row is `[1,3,  1,11,  9,14]`.

DEFINITION: ***`d_min` is the ***minimum difference*** between the elements of `two consecutive pairs`.***

The PROBLEM:  I want to retain rows of array `a`, where ***all consecutive pairs have `d_min <= c`***. Otherwise, the rows should be eliminated.

In the 1st array row, the 1st pair (1,3) and the 2nd pair (1,11) have `d_min = 1-1=0`.
The 2nd pair (1,11) and the 3rd pair(9,14) have `d_min = 11-9=2`.  (in both cases, `d_min<=c`, so we keep this row in `a`)

In the 2nd array row, the 1st pair (2,12) and the 2nd pair (1,10) have `d_min = 2-1=1`.
But, the 2nd pair (1,10) and the 3rd pair(7,6) have `d_min = 10-7=3`.  (3 > c, so this row should be eliminated from array `a`)

Current efforts:  I currently handle this problem with nested for-loops (2 deep).
The outer loop runs through the ***rows*** of array `a`, determining `d_min` between the first two pairs using:

```
for r in a
    d_min = np.amin(np.abs(np.subtract.outer(r[:2], r[2:4])))
```

The inner loop uses the same method to determine the `d_min` between the last two pairs.
Further processing only is done only when `d_min<= c` for both sets of consecutive pairs.
I'm really hoping there is a way to avoid the for-loops.  I eventually need to deal with 8-column arrays, and my current approach would involve 3-deep looping.

In the example, there are 4 row eliminations. The final result should look like:

```
a = np.array([[1, 3, 1, 11, 9, 14],
              [0, -3, 0, 3, -3, 0],
              [3, 14, 4, 12, 1, 4],
              [0, 13, 13, 4, 0, 3]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the number of elements in each row is always even:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 3, 1, 11, 9, 14],
              [2, 12, 1, 10, 7, 6],
              [6, 7, 2, 14, 2, 15],
              [14, 8, 1, 3, -7, 2],
              [0, -3, 0, 3, -3, 0],
              [2, 2, 3, 3, 12, 13],
              [3, 14, 4, 12, 1, 4],
              [0, 13, 13, 4, 0, 3]])
c = 2

# separate the array as previous pairs and next pairs
sx, sy = a.shape
prev_shape = sx, (sy - 2) // 2, 1, 2
next_shape = sx, (sy - 2) // 2, 2, 1

prev_pairs = a[:, :-2].reshape(prev_shape)
next_pairs = a[:, 2:].reshape(next_shape)

# subtract which will effectively work as outer subtraction due to numpy broadcasting, and 
# calculate the minimum difference for each pair
pair_diff_min = np.abs(prev_pairs - next_pairs).min(axis=(2, 3))

# calculate the filter condition as boolean array
to_keep = pair_diff_min.max(axis=1) <= c

print(a[to_keep])
#[[ 1  3  1 11  9 14]
# [ 0 -3  0  3 -3  0]
# [ 3 14  4 12  1  4]
# [ 0 13 13  4  0  3]]
```

[Demo Link](https://uscript.co/public/Google_108617488638529745626/python/a5d68527.py)

Comment: Very nice work, and instructive!  As a relative newcomer, it took me a while to understand how you used 4d arrays in broadcasting to facilitate the subtraction.  Really nice.